# Javascript code changing after html element is gone

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't have a lot of experience with Javascript and had to pay a guy to code me something. For some reason when I change something really simple in the code. The entire calculation process changes. I want to simply delete a option in the drop down menu and when I do that the entire GPA calculation method changes.
The javascript:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    let id = $(this).parent('th').next('td').find('input[type="text"]').attr("id")
    let value = $(this).val()
    $("#" + id).attr("id", value)
})

function gpa() {

    let credit = [
        {
            "9": {
                Regular: {
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                    Science: 1,
                    Math: 1,
                    English: 1,
                    Geography: 1,
                    PE: 0.5,
                    Art: 0.5,
                    Computer: 0.5,
                    Elective: 0.5,

                },
                Honers: {
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                    Science: 1,
                    Math: 1,
                    English: 1,
                    Geography: 1,
                    PE: 0.5,
                    Art: 0.5,
                    Computer: 0.5,
                    Elective: 0.5,
                    Trigonometry: 1,

                }
            }
        }, {
            "10": {
                Regular: {
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                    Science: 1,
                    Math: 1,
                    English: 1,
                    Geography: 1,
                    PE: 0.5,
                    Art: 0.5,
                    Computer: 0.5,
                    Elective: 0.5,
                    Biology: 1,
                    History: 1,
                    AlgebraII: 1,
                },
                Honers: {
                    English: 1,
                    Math: 1,
                    Science: 1,
                    Geography: 1,
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                    Elective: 0.5,
                    PE: 0.5,
                    Computer: 0.5,
                    Art: 0.5,
                    Biology: 1,
                    History: 1,
                    AlgebraII: 1,
                }
            }
        }, {
            "11": {
                IbCourses: {
                    English: 1,
                    IBEnglish: 1,
                    math: 1,
                    IBMath: 1,
                    Chemistry: 1,
                    History: 1,
                    arabic: 1,
                    islam: 0.5,
                    quran: 0.5,
                    elective: 1,
                },
                DP: {
                    IBEnglish: 1,
                    IBMath: 1,
                    IBChem: 1,
                    IBPhysics: 1,
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                    TOK: 1,
                    IBElective: 1,
                    IBArabic: 1,
                    IBSpanish: 1,
                }
            }
        }, {
            "12": {
                IbCourses: {
                    English: 1,
                    IBEnglish: 1,
                    Math: 1,
                    IBMath: 1,
                    IBElective: 1,
                    elective: 1,
                    Physics: 1,
                    IBPhysics: 1,
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                },
                DP: {
                    IBEnglish: 1,
                    IBMath: 1,
                    IBChem: 1,
                    IBPhysics: 1,
                    IBElective: 1,
                    IBArabic: 1,
                    IBSpanish: 1,
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                    TOK: 1,
                }
            }
        }
    ]

    let gpa = [
        {
            Regular: {
                94: 4,
                91: 3.7,
                88: 3.3,
                85: 3,
                81: 2.7,
                78: 2.3,
                74: 2,
                71: 1.7,
                68: 1.3,
                64: 1,
                61: 0.7,
                54: 0
            }
        },
        {
            Honers: {
                94: 4.2,
                91: 3.9,
                88: 3.5,
                85: 3.2,
                81: 2.9,
                78: 2.5,
                74: 2.2,
                71: 1.9,
                68: 1.5,
                64: 1.2,
                61: 0.9,
                54: 0
            }
        },
        {
            IbCourses: {
                94: 4.5,
                91: 4.2,
                88: 3.8,
                85: 3.5,
                81: 3.2,
                78: 2.8,
                74: 2.5,
                71: 2.2,
                68: 1.8,
                64: 1.5,
                61: 1.2,
                54: 0
            }
        },
        {
            DP: {
                94: 5,
                91: 4.7,
                88: 4.3,
                85: 4,
                81: 3.7,
                78: 3.3,
                74: 3,
                71: 2.7,
                68: 2.3,
                64: 2,
                61: 1.7,
                54: 0
            }
        },
        {
            HalfCredits: {
                94: 2,
                91: 1.85,
                88: 1.65,
                85: 1.5,
                81: 1.35,
                78: 1.15,
                74: 1,
                71: 0.85,
                68: 0.65,
                64: 0.5,
                61: 0.35,
                54: 0
            }
        }
    ]

    let special = {
        9: {
            Science: 0.2,
            Math: 0.2,
            English: 0.2,
            Geography: 0.2,
            Trigonometry: 0.2,
        },
        10: {
            Biology: 0.2,
            Math: 0.2,
            English: 0.2,
            History: 0.2,
        },
        11: {
            IbCourses: {
                IBEnglish: 0.5,
                IBMath: 0.5,
                elective: 0.5,
            },
            DP: {
                IBEnglish: 1,
                IBMath: 1,
                IBElective: 1,
                IBChem: 1,
                IBArabic: 1,
                IBSpanish: 1,
                IBPhysics: 1,
            },
            EZ: {
                IBEnglish: 0.5,
                IBMath: 0.5,
                IBElective: 0.5,
                IBChemistry: 0.5,
                IBArabic: 0.5,
                IBSpanish: 0.5,
                Chemistry: 0.5,
                History: 0.5,
                IBGlobalPolitics: 0.5,
            }
        },
        12: {
            IbCourses: {
                IBEnglish: 0.5,
                IBMath: 0.5,
                IBElective: 0.5,
                IBPhysics: 0.5,
            },
            DP: {
                IBEnglish: 1,
                IBMath: 1,
                IBChem: 1,
                IBPhysics: 1,
                IBElective: 1,
                IBArabic: 1,
                IBSpanish: 1,
            }
        }
    }

    let subjects = []
    let data = []
    let grade = $('#grade').val()
    let certificate = $('#certificate').val()

    // Select Subjects Selected or already there
    $('#subjectTbl input[type="text"]').each(function () {
        subjects.push($(this).attr('id'))
    });
    // need change

    subjects.forEach(element => {
        data.push({
            [element]: $('#' + element).val() != "" ? $('#' + element).val() : 0
        })
    })

    let cr = {}
    credit.forEach(item => {
        Object.keys(item).map(key => {
            Object.values(item).map(elm => {
                if (key === grade) {
                    Object.keys(elm).map(itm => {
                        if (itm === certificate) {
                            Object.assign(cr, elm[itm])
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    })



    let gp = {}
    gpa.forEach(element => {
        Object.keys(element).map(key => {
            if (key === "Regular") {
                Object.assign(gp, element[key])
            }
        })
    })


    let sp = {}
    Object.keys(special).map(element => {
        if (element === grade) {
            if (element == "11" || element == "12") {
                Object.keys(special[element]).map(ite => {
                    if (ite.toLocaleLowerCase() === certificate.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
                        Object.assign(sp, special[element][ite])
                    }
                })
            }
            console.log(sp)
            if (element != "11" || element != "12") {
                Object.assign(sp, special[element])
            }

        }
    })

    data.forEach(element => {
        if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 93 && Object.values(element)[0] <= 100) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 93, 100)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 90 && Object.values(element)[0] < 93) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 90, 93)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 87 && Object.values(element)[0] < 90) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 87, 90)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 83 && Object.values(element)[0] < 87) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 83, 87)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 80 && Object.values(element)[0] < 83) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 80, 83)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 77 && Object.values(element)[0] < 80) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 77, 80)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 73 && Object.values(element)[0] < 77) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 73, 77)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 70 && Object.values(element)[0] < 73) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 70, 73)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 67 && Object.values(element)[0] < 70) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 67, 70)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 63 && Object.values(element)[0] < 67) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 63, 67)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 60 && Object.values(element)[0] < 63) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 60, 63)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 0 && Object.values(element)[0] < 60) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 0, 60)
        }
    })

    function setGpaCredits(element, lgrade, hgrade) {
        let gpaSel = 0
        let creditSel = 0
        let aditionalGpa = 0
        Object.keys(gp).map(elem => {
            if (elem > lgrade && elem < hgrade)
                gpaSel = gp[elem]
        })
        Object.keys(cr).map(elem => {
            Object.keys(element).map(item => {
                if (elem.toLocaleLowerCase() === item.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
                    creditSel = cr[elem]
                    if (certificate === "Honers" || certificate === "DP" || certificate === "IbCourses") {
                        if (hgrade >= 60) {
                            aditionalGpa = sp[elem]
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        })
        console.log(creditSel)
        Object.assign(element, { gpa: gpaSel + (aditionalGpa ? aditionalGpa : 0), credit: creditSel, subjectGpa: (aditionalGpa ? aditionalGpa : 0) + gpaSel * creditSel })
    }



    console.log(data)
    let fullGpa = 0
    let fullCredit = 0
    data.forEach(item => {
        let valu
        item.gpa > 0 && item.credit > 0 ? valu = item.gpa * item.credit : valu = 0

        fullGpa += valu
        fullCredit += item.credit
    })
    let finalGpa = fullGpa / fullCredit
    console.log(fullGpa, fullCredit, finalGpa)

    $('#finalGpa').empty()
    $('#finalGpa').append("<h1> Your GPA is " + finalGpa.toFixed(2) + "</h2>")
    $('#finalGpa').css("display", "block")

    $('#resultDiv').css("display", "block")

    $('#resultDivBtn').on('click', function () {
        $('#resultDivAll').empty()
        $('#resultDivAll').append("<div class='col-md-12 text-center'>" +
            "<span><strong>Notice:</strong> Each grade has a different formula for calculating GPA.</span>" +
            "<span>First, you get all your percentages and you convert them to GPAs' using this chart.</span>" +
            "<span><strong>Percentage/GPA Chart<strong></span>" +
            "" +
            "</div>")
        $('#resultDivAll').css("display", "block")
    })
}
```

The HTML before the changes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>ACA NHS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64" href="favico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="favico/favicon-192.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="160x160" href="favico/favicon-160.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="favico/favicon-96.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="64x64" href="favico/favicon-64.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favico/favicon-32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favico/favicon-16.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favico/favicon-57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="favico/favicon-114.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="favico/favicon-72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="favico/favicon-144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="favico/favicon-60.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="favico/favicon-120.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="favico/favicon-76.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="favico/favicon-152.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favico/favicon-180.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="favico/favicon-144.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-config" content="favico/browserconfig.xml">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    </head>
</header>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
     integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" 
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <img src="../logo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="HTML tag">
    <p class="bluebackground">&emsp;</p>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="boyshome.html">Boys Campus</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="girlshome.html">Girls Campus</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="../../gpacalculator.html">GPA Calculator</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
            <h3>GPA Calculator (12th Grade Courses)</h3>
            <h4>Please insert your percentages</h4>
            <input type="hidden" id="grade" value="12" />
            <input type="hidden" id="certificate" value="IbCourses">
            <div id="finalGpa" style="display: none;"></div>
            <table >
                <thead style="text-align: center;">
                  <tr>
                    <th >Subject</th>
                    <th >Percentages</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="subjectTbl">
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="select">(select subject)</option>
                            <option value="English"> English</option>
                            <option value="IBEnglish">IB English</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="IBEnglish"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="select">(select subject)</option>
                            <option value="math"> Regular Math</option>
                            <option value="IBMath"> IB math</option>
                            <option value="Elective"> Elective</option>
                            <option value="IBElective"> IB Elective</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="IBElective"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="select">(select subject)</option>
                            <option value="Physics"> Physics</option>
                            <option value="IBPhysics"> IB physics</option>
                            <option value="Elective"> Elective</option>
                            <option value="IBElective"> IB Elective</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="Physics"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">Arabic</th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="Arabic"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">Islam</th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="Islam"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">Quran</th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="Quran"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="select">(select Elective 1)</option>
                            <option value="IBElective"> IB Elective</option>
                            <option value="Elective"> regular Elective</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="quran"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="select">(select Elective 2)</option>
                            <option value="IBElective"> IB Elective</option>
                            <option value="Elective"> regular Elective</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="elective"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button id="gpa" onclick="gpa()">Get GPA</button>
        </div>
        <div id="resultDiv" style="display: none;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <button id="resultDivBtn">Show GPA</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="resultDivAll" style="display: none;" >
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer-distributed">
        <div class="footer-left">
            <h3>NHS<span>ACA</span></h3>
            <p class="footer-links">Boys Campus:</p>
            <p class="footer-links">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/nhsb.aca/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                 nhsb.aca</a>&emsp;
                 |&emsp;
                 <a href="mailto:nhsb.aca@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                nhsb.aca@gmail.com</a>
            </p>
            <p class="footer-links">Girls Campus:</p>
            <p class="footer-links">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/aca.nhs/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                 aca.nhs</a>&emsp;
                  |&emsp;
                 <a href="mailto:acanational.hs@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                acanational.hs@gmail.com</a>
            </p>
            <br>
            <p class="footer-company-name">© Mohammad al Nusif</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-center">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
            <div>
                <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/B3vW2nPkNewZUyxW9"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <p>Boys Campus Map</p></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/uKS7qgy5P6F8csRK7"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <p>Girls Campus Map</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-right">
            <p class="footer-company-about">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <span>Boys Campus:</span>
                Advisor's Email - sali.alkhuraishi@aca.edu.kw<br>
                President's Email - bahaabed2003@gmail.com<br>
                Vice President's Email - azoibi17@gmail.com<br>
                <br>
                <span>Girls Campus:</span>
                Advisor's Email - nicole.depew@aca.edu.kw<br>
                President's Email - kayanalghanim@gmail.com<br>
                Vice President's Email - skkh03@gmail.com <br>
                <br>
            <div class="footer-icons">
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
<script src="../gpascripts/grade9.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#resultDivBtn").click(function(){
            $("#resultDivBtn").hide();
          });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

The HTML after:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>ACA NHS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64" href="favico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="favico/favicon-192.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="160x160" href="favico/favicon-160.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="favico/favicon-96.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="64x64" href="favico/favicon-64.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favico/favicon-32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favico/favicon-16.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favico/favicon-57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="favico/favicon-114.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="favico/favicon-72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="favico/favicon-144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="favico/favicon-60.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="favico/favicon-120.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="favico/favicon-76.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="favico/favicon-152.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favico/favicon-180.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="favico/favicon-144.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-config" content="favico/browserconfig.xml">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    </head>
</header>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
     integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" 
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <img src="../logo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="HTML tag">
    <p class="bluebackground">&emsp;</p>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="boyshome.html">Boys Campus</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="girlshome.html">Girls Campus</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="../../gpacalculator.html">GPA Calculator</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
            <h3>GPA Calculator (12th Grade Courses)</h3>
            <h4>Please insert your percentages</h4>
            <input type="hidden" id="grade" value="12" />
            <input type="hidden" id="certificate" value="IbCourses">
            <div id="finalGpa" style="display: none;"></div>
            <table >
                <thead style="text-align: center;">
                  <tr>
                    <th >Subject</th>
                    <th >Percentages</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="subjectTbl">
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="English"> English</option>
                            <option value="IBEnglish">IB English</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="IBEnglish"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="select">(select subject)</option>
                            <option value="math"> Regular Math</option>
                            <option value="IBMath"> IB math</option>
                            <option value="Elective"> Elective</option>
                            <option value="IBElective"> IB Elective</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="IBElective"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="select">(select subject)</option>
                            <option value="Physics"> Physics</option>
                            <option value="IBPhysics"> IB physics</option>
                            <option value="Elective"> Elective</option>
                            <option value="IBElective"> IB Elective</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="Physics"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">Arabic</th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="Arabic"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">Islam</th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="Islam"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">Quran</th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="Quran"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="select">(select Elective 1)</option>
                            <option value="IBElective"> IB Elective</option>
                            <option value="Elective"> regular Elective</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="quran"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="select">(select Elective 2)</option>
                            <option value="IBElective"> IB Elective</option>
                            <option value="Elective"> regular Elective</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="elective"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button id="gpa" onclick="gpa()">Get GPA</button>
        </div>
        <div id="resultDiv" style="display: none;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <button id="resultDivBtn">Show GPA</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="resultDivAll" style="display: none;" >
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer-distributed">
        <div class="footer-left">
            <h3>NHS<span>ACA</span></h3>
            <p class="footer-links">Boys Campus:</p>
            <p class="footer-links">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/nhsb.aca/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                 nhsb.aca</a>&emsp;
                 |&emsp;
                 <a href="mailto:nhsb.aca@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                nhsb.aca@gmail.com</a>
            </p>
            <p class="footer-links">Girls Campus:</p>
            <p class="footer-links">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/aca.nhs/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                 aca.nhs</a>&emsp;
                  |&emsp;
                 <a href="mailto:acanational.hs@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                acanational.hs@gmail.com</a>
            </p>
            <br>
            <p class="footer-company-name">© Mohammad al Nusif</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-center">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
            <div>
                <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/B3vW2nPkNewZUyxW9"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <p>Boys Campus Map</p></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/uKS7qgy5P6F8csRK7"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <p>Girls Campus Map</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-right">
            <p class="footer-company-about">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <span>Boys Campus:</span>
                Advisor's Email - sali.alkhuraishi@aca.edu.kw<br>
                President's Email - bahaabed2003@gmail.com<br>
                Vice President's Email - azoibi17@gmail.com<br>
                <br>
                <span>Girls Campus:</span>
                Advisor's Email - nicole.depew@aca.edu.kw<br>
                President's Email - kayanalghanim@gmail.com<br>
                Vice President's Email - skkh03@gmail.com <br>
                <br>
            <div class="footer-icons">
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
<script src="../gpascripts/grade9.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#resultDivBtn").click(function(){
            $("#resultDivBtn").hide();
          });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Before html change:

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ARW3.png)

After html change:

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU36j.png)

Basically all I did was delete the select subject as a drop down menu option on line 74. This is a simple html change I don't understand how this in turn affects the javascript.

Comment: Will you upload screenshot or sample values to test?

Comment: what error do you experience? Of course it affects the javascript because it´s based on each other.

Comment: My *guess* based on a quick look is that they used the index of the selected class from the list of all the classes in the dropdown and that messed up when you basically shifted all indexes - 1

Comment: The problem here is that event is fired only on "onchange" event. When you select a course, it onchange event is triggered and the nearest input value is saved as an attribute which is used later on. So, when you delete the first value and don't change the selection, it uses wrong index value. But even if you delete and change the selection and change back to the first one (shown by default) then it works fine.

Comment: @StefanWang I just did.

Comment: @johnSmith I get the wrong answer

Comment: @Samathingamajig any idea on how I can change the index?

Comment: @Lakshya figured that. But I don't understand javascript at all. Any idea on how I can change the index?

Answer (score 1):

When you remove the first option, your first option automatically becomes the first value in the dropdown but when you click on Get GPA button without changing the value even once, id of the input box next to the dropdown changes to have id of selected option. So, there's an easy way to correct it.
When you remove the select option, give default id to the input boxes same as the value of the first option.

I have corrected the html and [here's the working code](https://jsfiddle.net/5q0kezo4/).

```js
$('select').on('change', function () {
    let id = $(this).parent('th').next('td').find('input[type="text"]').attr("id")
    let value = $(this).val()
    $("#" + id).attr("id", value)
    console.log(id);
})

function gpa() {

    let credit = [
        {
            "9": {
                Regular: {
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                    Science: 1,
                    Math: 1,
                    English: 1,
                    Geography: 1,
                    PE: 0.5,
                    Art: 0.5,
                    Computer: 0.5,
                    Elective: 0.5,

                },
                Honers: {
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                    Science: 1,
                    Math: 1,
                    English: 1,
                    Geography: 1,
                    PE: 0.5,
                    Art: 0.5,
                    Computer: 0.5,
                    Elective: 0.5,
                    Trigonometry: 1,

                }
            }
        }, {
            "10": {
                Regular: {
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                    Science: 1,
                    Math: 1,
                    English: 1,
                    Geography: 1,
                    PE: 0.5,
                    Art: 0.5,
                    Computer: 0.5,
                    Elective: 0.5,
                    Biology: 1,
                    History: 1,
                    AlgebraII: 1,
                },
                Honers: {
                    English: 1,
                    Math: 1,
                    Science: 1,
                    Geography: 1,
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                    Elective: 0.5,
                    PE: 0.5,
                    Computer: 0.5,
                    Art: 0.5,
                    Biology: 1,
                    History: 1,
                    AlgebraII: 1,
                }
            }
        }, {
            "11": {
                IbCourses: {
                    English: 1,
                    IBEnglish: 1,
                    math: 1,
                    IBMath: 1,
                    Chemistry: 1,
                    History: 1,
                    arabic: 1,
                    islam: 0.5,
                    quran: 0.5,
                    elective: 1,
                },
                DP: {
                    IBEnglish: 1,
                    IBMath: 1,
                    IBChem: 1,
                    IBPhysics: 1,
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                    TOK: 1,
                    IBElective: 1,
                    IBArabic: 1,
                    IBSpanish: 1,
                }
            }
        }, {
            "12": {
                IbCourses: {
                    English: 1,
                    IBEnglish: 1,
                    Math: 1,
                    IBMath: 1,
                    IBElective: 1,
                    elective: 1,
                    Physics: 1,
                    IBPhysics: 1,
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                },
                DP: {
                    IBEnglish: 1,
                    IBMath: 1,
                    IBChem: 1,
                    IBPhysics: 1,
                    IBElective: 1,
                    IBArabic: 1,
                    IBSpanish: 1,
                    Arabic: 1,
                    Islam: 0.5,
                    Quran: 0.5,
                    TOK: 1,
                }
            }
        }
    ]

    let gpa = [
        {
            Regular: {
                94: 4,
                91: 3.7,
                88: 3.3,
                85: 3,
                81: 2.7,
                78: 2.3,
                74: 2,
                71: 1.7,
                68: 1.3,
                64: 1,
                61: 0.7,
                54: 0
            }
        },
        {
            Honers: {
                94: 4.2,
                91: 3.9,
                88: 3.5,
                85: 3.2,
                81: 2.9,
                78: 2.5,
                74: 2.2,
                71: 1.9,
                68: 1.5,
                64: 1.2,
                61: 0.9,
                54: 0
            }
        },
        {
            IbCourses: {
                94: 4.5,
                91: 4.2,
                88: 3.8,
                85: 3.5,
                81: 3.2,
                78: 2.8,
                74: 2.5,
                71: 2.2,
                68: 1.8,
                64: 1.5,
                61: 1.2,
                54: 0
            }
        },
        {
            DP: {
                94: 5,
                91: 4.7,
                88: 4.3,
                85: 4,
                81: 3.7,
                78: 3.3,
                74: 3,
                71: 2.7,
                68: 2.3,
                64: 2,
                61: 1.7,
                54: 0
            }
        },
        {
            HalfCredits: {
                94: 2,
                91: 1.85,
                88: 1.65,
                85: 1.5,
                81: 1.35,
                78: 1.15,
                74: 1,
                71: 0.85,
                68: 0.65,
                64: 0.5,
                61: 0.35,
                54: 0
            }
        }
    ]

    let special = {
        9: {
            Science: 0.2,
            Math: 0.2,
            English: 0.2,
            Geography: 0.2,
            Trigonometry: 0.2,
        },
        10: {
            Biology: 0.2,
            Math: 0.2,
            English: 0.2,
            History: 0.2,
        },
        11: {
            IbCourses: {
                IBEnglish: 0.5,
                IBMath: 0.5,
                elective: 0.5,
            },
            DP: {
                IBEnglish: 1,
                IBMath: 1,
                IBElective: 1,
                IBChem: 1,
                IBArabic: 1,
                IBSpanish: 1,
                IBPhysics: 1,
            },
            EZ: {
                IBEnglish: 0.5,
                IBMath: 0.5,
                IBElective: 0.5,
                IBChemistry: 0.5,
                IBArabic: 0.5,
                IBSpanish: 0.5,
                Chemistry: 0.5,
                History: 0.5,
                IBGlobalPolitics: 0.5,
            }
        },
        12: {
            IbCourses: {
                IBEnglish: 0.5,
                IBMath: 0.5,
                IBElective: 0.5,
                IBPhysics: 0.5,
            },
            DP: {
                IBEnglish: 1,
                IBMath: 1,
                IBChem: 1,
                IBPhysics: 1,
                IBElective: 1,
                IBArabic: 1,
                IBSpanish: 1,
            }
        }
    }

    let subjects = []
    let data = []
    let grade = $('#grade').val()
    let certificate = $('#certificate').val()

    // Select Subjects Selected or already there
    $('#subjectTbl input[type="text"]').each(function () {
        subjects.push($(this).attr('id'))
    });
    // need change

    subjects.forEach(element => {
        data.push({
            [element]: $('#' + element).val() != "" ? $('#' + element).val() : 0
        })
    })

    let cr = {}
    credit.forEach(item => {
        Object.keys(item).map(key => {
            Object.values(item).map(elm => {
                if (key === grade) {
                    Object.keys(elm).map(itm => {
                        if (itm === certificate) {
                            Object.assign(cr, elm[itm])
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    })



    let gp = {}
    gpa.forEach(element => {
        Object.keys(element).map(key => {
            if (key === "Regular") {
                Object.assign(gp, element[key])
            }
        })
    })


    let sp = {}
    Object.keys(special).map(element => {
        if (element === grade) {
            if (element == "11" || element == "12") {
                Object.keys(special[element]).map(ite => {
                    if (ite.toLocaleLowerCase() === certificate.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
                        Object.assign(sp, special[element][ite])
                    }
                })
            }
            console.log(sp)
            if (element != "11" || element != "12") {
                Object.assign(sp, special[element])
            }

        }
    })

    data.forEach(element => {
        if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 93 && Object.values(element)[0] <= 100) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 93, 100)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 90 && Object.values(element)[0] < 93) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 90, 93)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 87 && Object.values(element)[0] < 90) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 87, 90)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 83 && Object.values(element)[0] < 87) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 83, 87)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 80 && Object.values(element)[0] < 83) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 80, 83)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 77 && Object.values(element)[0] < 80) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 77, 80)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 73 && Object.values(element)[0] < 77) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 73, 77)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 70 && Object.values(element)[0] < 73) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 70, 73)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 67 && Object.values(element)[0] < 70) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 67, 70)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 63 && Object.values(element)[0] < 67) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 63, 67)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 60 && Object.values(element)[0] < 63) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 60, 63)
        } else if (Object.values(element)[0] >= 0 && Object.values(element)[0] < 60) {
            setGpaCredits(element, 0, 60)
        }
    })

    function setGpaCredits(element, lgrade, hgrade) {
        let gpaSel = 0
        let creditSel = 0
        let aditionalGpa = 0
        Object.keys(gp).map(elem => {
            if (elem > lgrade && elem < hgrade)
                gpaSel = gp[elem]
        })
        Object.keys(cr).map(elem => {
            Object.keys(element).map(item => {
                if (elem.toLocaleLowerCase() === item.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
                    creditSel = cr[elem]
                    if (certificate === "Honers" || certificate === "DP" || certificate === "IbCourses") {
                        if (hgrade >= 60) {
                            aditionalGpa = sp[elem]
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        })
        console.log(creditSel)
        Object.assign(element, { gpa: gpaSel + (aditionalGpa ? aditionalGpa : 0), credit: creditSel, subjectGpa: (aditionalGpa ? aditionalGpa : 0) + gpaSel * creditSel })
    }



    console.log(data)
    let fullGpa = 0
    let fullCredit = 0
    data.forEach(item => {
        let valu
        item.gpa > 0 && item.credit > 0 ? valu = item.gpa * item.credit : valu = 0

        fullGpa += valu
        fullCredit += item.credit
    })
    let finalGpa = fullGpa / fullCredit
    console.log(fullGpa, fullCredit, finalGpa)

    $('#finalGpa').empty()
    $('#finalGpa').append("<h1> Your GPA is " + finalGpa.toFixed(2) + "</h2>")
    $('#finalGpa').css("display", "block")

    $('#resultDiv').css("display", "block")

    $('#resultDivBtn').on('click', function () {
        $('#resultDivAll').empty()
        $('#resultDivAll').append("<div class='col-md-12 text-center'>" +
            "<span><strong>Notice:</strong> Each grade has a different formula for calculating GPA.</span>" +
            "<span>First, you get all your percentages and you convert them to GPAs' using this chart.</span>" +
            "<span><strong>Percentage/GPA Chart<strong></span>" +
            "" +
            "</div>")
        $('#resultDivAll').css("display", "block")
    })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>ACA NHS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64" href="favico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="favico/favicon-192.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="160x160" href="favico/favicon-160.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="favico/favicon-96.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="64x64" href="favico/favicon-64.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favico/favicon-32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favico/favicon-16.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favico/favicon-57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="favico/favicon-114.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="favico/favicon-72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="favico/favicon-144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="favico/favicon-60.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="favico/favicon-120.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="favico/favicon-76.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="favico/favicon-152.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favico/favicon-180.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="favico/favicon-144.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-config" content="favico/browserconfig.xml">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    </head>
</header>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
     integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" 
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <img src="../logo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="HTML tag">
    <p class="bluebackground">&emsp;</p>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="boyshome.html">Boys Campus</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="girlshome.html">Girls Campus</a></li>
          <li class="navlist"><a class="active" href="../../gpacalculator.html">GPA Calculator</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
            <h3>GPA Calculator (12th Grade Courses)</h3>
            <h4>Please insert your percentages</h4>
            <input type="hidden" id="grade" value="12" />
            <input type="hidden" id="certificate" value="IbCourses">
            <div id="finalGpa" style="display: none;"></div>
            <table >
                <thead style="text-align: center;">
                  <tr>
                    <th >Subject</th>
                    <th >Percentages</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="subjectTbl">
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="English"> English</option>
                            <option value="IBEnglish">IB English</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="English"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="math"> Regular Math</option>
                            <option value="IBMath"> IB math</option>
                            <option value="Elective"> Elective</option>
                            <option value="IBElective"> IB Elective</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="math"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="Physics"> Physics</option>
                            <option value="IBPhysics"> IB physics</option>
                            <option value="Elective"> Elective</option>
                            <option value="IBElective"> IB Elective</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="Physics"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">Arabic</th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="Arabic"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">Islam</th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="Islam"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">Quran</th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="Quran"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                            <option value="Elective"> regular Elective</option>
<option value="IBElective"> IB Elective</option>
                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="quran"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <select>
                                                    <option value="Elective"> regular Elective</option>
                            <option value="IBElective"> IB Elective</option>

                        </select>
                      </th>
                      <td><input type="text" id="elective"> &nbsp; %</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button id="gpa" onclick="gpa()">Get GPA</button>
        </div>
        <div id="resultDiv" style="display: none;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <button id="resultDivBtn">Show GPA</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="resultDivAll" style="display: none;" >
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer-distributed">
        <div class="footer-left">
            <h3>NHS<span>ACA</span></h3>
            <p class="footer-links">Boys Campus:</p>
            <p class="footer-links">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/nhsb.aca/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                 nhsb.aca</a>&emsp;
                 |&emsp;
                 <a href="mailto:nhsb.aca@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                nhsb.aca@gmail.com</a>
            </p>
            <p class="footer-links">Girls Campus:</p>
            <p class="footer-links">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/aca.nhs/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                 aca.nhs</a>&emsp;
                  |&emsp;
                 <a href="mailto:acanational.hs@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                acanational.hs@gmail.com</a>
            </p>
            <br>
            <p class="footer-company-name">© Mohammad al Nusif</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-center">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
            <div>
                <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/B3vW2nPkNewZUyxW9"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <p>Boys Campus Map</p></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/uKS7qgy5P6F8csRK7"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <p>Girls Campus Map</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-right">
            <p class="footer-company-about">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <span>Boys Campus:</span>
                Advisor's Email - sali.alkhuraishi@aca.edu.kw<br>
                President's Email - bahaabed2003@gmail.com<br>
                Vice President's Email - azoibi17@gmail.com<br>
                <br>
                <span>Girls Campus:</span>
                Advisor's Email - nicole.depew@aca.edu.kw<br>
                President's Email - kayanalghanim@gmail.com<br>
                Vice President's Email - skkh03@gmail.com <br>
                <br>
            <div class="footer-icons">
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
<script src="../gpascripts/grade9.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#resultDivBtn").click(function(){
            $("#resultDivBtn").hide();
          });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey I'm sorry I'm kinda a js noob. Can you please tell me which parts you edited? So I can do the same to the other drop down sections? Thanks!

Comment: In the above code, I have edited for all the drop down sections. Changes are only in HTML, there's no change in JS.
Just changed the id of input box to make it same as that of the first option's value (everywhere).
1. https://imgur.com/iKkJ805 2. https://imgur.com/E3qXF1c